# Autocomplete gives me the name of someone not in the chat room?

Tags: support, chat, autocomplete

I was looking for Zypher in the Teachers Lounge chat, and he showed up in the autocomplete, so I assumed he was in the room. But no:

[image]

That's the autocomplete

[image]

That's the list of people in the room

[image]

And that's Zypher's gravatar, which if you squint hard enough you'll see that he's not in that room (whether he's on chat at all, I don't know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's absolutely correct and intentional.

The autocomplete names that you get offered are all names that the client thinks you know about, which is every name it saw since you opened the chat page in the browsers ("saw" being defined as either being in the room, or at least having a message visible).

The autocompleter has nothing to do with the question of "Who's here" -- except that the former is always a superset of the latter.

Side note: The room info page – [like this one](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/the-tavern-general) – also shows you who's in the room; that may be a bit easier than finding a faded out gravatar in the room.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I'm just used to autocomplete only autocompleting things that are present.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, if they've been in the room recently you can still mention them by their full name... but I'll take a look and check that the current behaviour is intentional. It may be simply acting cumulatively, for example. Had that browser session been open a long time?

Comment: yeah it had been open for about 5 hours