# Make usernames auto-completable for as long as user is notifiable

Tags: feature-request, chat

It doesn't make much sense that I am able to notify a user on chat, yet I can't auto-complete their usernames if I haven't seen them in the room.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab name completion for comments please!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please)

Comment: @YOU: check the tag.

Comment: Ummmmm, chat? Isn't already there? Type "@" and then type username, and press Tab.

Comment: @YOU It doesn't work for people you haven't seen in the room (i.e. they left before you joined)

Comment: @Michael, I see, Thanks for edit. It will be contradict with [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78621/autocomplete-gives-me-the-name-of-someone-not-in-the-chat-room) IMHO.

Comment: Oh, I guess anyone with a visible message counts too; I didn't know that part

Comment: This would also help with "I wonder if this person will actually get a notification" as you're sending the message.

Comment: Rules for when pinging will work, even when auto-complete might not: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/939